# strange problem with mysql stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

It's just for test,

but pretty strange:

```
    DELIMITER |

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_idiscussion_ask|

CREATE FUNCTION get_idiscussion_ask(iask_id INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE body varchar(600);
  DECLARE created DATETIME;
  DECLARE anonymous TINYINT(1);
  DECLARE screen_name varchar(64);
  DECLARE result TEXT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT body,created,anonymous,screen_name from idiscussion left join users on idiscussion.uid=users.id where idiscussion.iask_id=iask_id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  SET result = '';
  OPEN cur1;
  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO body, created, anonymous, screen_name;
    SET result = CONCAT(result,'<comment><body><![CDATA[',body,']]></body>','<replier>',if(screen_name is not null and !anonymous,screen_name,''),'</replier>','<created>',created,'</created></comment>');
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE cur1;

  RETURN result;
END |

DELIMITER ;

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> select get_idiscussion_ask(1);
+------------------------+
| get_idiscussion_ask(1) |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)



mysql> SELECT body,created,anonymous,screen_name from idiscussion left join users on idiscussion.uid=users.id where idiscussion.iask_id=1;
+------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+
| body | created             | anonymous | screen_name |
+------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+
| haha | 2009-05-27 04:57:51 |         0 | NULL        |
| haha | 2009-05-27 04:57:52 |         0 | NULL        |
| haha | 2009-05-27 04:57:52 |         0 | NULL        |
| haha | 2009-05-27 04:57:53 |         0 | NULL        |
+------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why are you running the concat() function if your function is called 'get_idiscussion_ask'?

Comment: copy paste error...
should be call that function,and it returns null..

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
Select Result
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You are not calling your function in your example.

2) concatenating anything with null results in null

Answer (score 0):

You...concat a null and a string... which is a null. What does the stored procedure have anything to do with it if you don't even call it?

Answer (score 0):

if you change this:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT body,created,anonymous,screen_name 
  FROM idiscussion 
  LEFT JOIN users ON idiscussion.uid=users.id 
  WHERE idiscussion.iask_id=iask_id;
```

to

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT   
ifnull(body,'')  
,ifnull(created,now())    
,ifnull(anonymous,0)  
,ifnull(screen_name,'')  
FROM idiscussion   
LEFT JOIN users on idiscussion.uid=users.id   
WHERE idiscussion.iask_id=iask_id;
```

You should not have any problems with CONCATing nulls

also I'm wondering if this part
`where idiscussion.iask_id=iask_id;`
does not give a name conflict maybe you should change the parameter
iask_id to
piask_id
(but I'm not sure on that part).